# I tried to play the audio on Alexa skill from my S3 Bucket, from the test tab, **it show <audio only response> but in fact, I can't hear any sound

Tags: python, audio, ffmpeg, alexa-skills-kit

So I tried to play the audio on Alexa skill from my S3 Bucket, from the test tab, **it show  but in fact, I can't hear any sound**. Another fact is, that I tried to use the sample audio from https://developer.amazon.com/en-US/docs/alexa/custom-skills/ask-soundlibrary.html and **it is worked, but why it won't work when it comes from my own S3 Bucket?**

Notes:

I've tried to test the skill using my mobile phone also.

I've tried to encode the audio using FFmpeg.

I've tried to use Jovo to convert the audio. https://v3.jovo.tech/audio-converter

I don't know how to fix this error.

There is no error message on cloud watch.

Assumptions:
There is some problem related to the audio resources or there is more set to play audio from S3 Bucket since the sample audio is working.

Steps to reproduce:

> Build the interaction model

> Encode the audio to make it Alexa skill friendly (fulfill the requirements, like sample rate, etc), I used and tried all of these:

A:

```
ffmpeg -i <input-file> -ac 2 -codec:a libmp3lame -b:a 48k -ar 16000 -write_xing 0 <output-file>
```

B:

```
ffmpeg -i <input-file> -ac 2 -codec:a libmp3lame -b:a 48k -ar 24000 -write_xing 0 <output-file>
```

C:

```
ffmpeg -y -i input.mp3 -ar 16000 -ab 48k -codec:a libmp3lame -ac 1 output.mp3
```

> Upload the audio resources on S3Bucket
> [Audio sample on s3 storage but none of them are produce any sounds](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A8ID5.png)

> Use the link and insert it to APLA.json

```
    {
      "type": "APLA",
      "version": "0.91",
      "description": "Simple document that generates speech",
      "mainTemplate": {
        "parameters": [
          "payload"
        ],
        "type": "Sequencer",
        "items": [
          {
            "type": "Audio",
            "source": "https://72578561-d9d8-47b4-811c-cafbcbc5ddb9-us-east-1.s3.amazonaws.com/Media/one-small-step-alexa-24.mp3"
          }
        ]
      }
    }
```

notes: I change the link sources based on audio that I tried.

> the intent on lambda_function.py:

```
def _load_apl_document(file_path):
    # type: (str) -> Dict[str, Any]
    """Load the apl json document at the path into a dict object."""
    with open(file_path) as f:
        return json.load(f)

class LaunchRequestHandler(AbstractRequestHandler):
    """Handler for Skill Launch."""
    def can_handle(self, handler_input):
        # type: (HandlerInput) -> bool

        return ask_utils.is_request_type("LaunchRequest")(handler_input)

    def handle(self, handler_input):
        # type: (HandlerInput) -> Response
        logger.info("In LaunchRequestHandler")

        # type: (HandlerInput) -> Response
        speak_output = "Hello World!"
        # .ask("add a reprompt if you want to keep the session open for the user to respond")

        return (
            handler_input.response_builder
                #.speak(speak_output)
                .add_directive(
                        RenderDocumentDirective(
                            token="pagerToken",
                            document=_load_apl_document("APLA.json"),
                            datasources={}
                        )
                    )
                .response
        )
```

> Deploy

> Test it

> The result of the test on my end:
>
> [The response for testing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xrtLs.png)

the JSON response:

```
{
    "body": {
        "version": "1.0",
        "response": {
            "directives": [
                {
                    "type": "Alexa.Presentation.APLA.RenderDocument",
                    "token": "pagerToken",
                    "document": {
                        "type": "APLA",
                        "version": "0.91",
                        "description": "Simple document that generates speech",
                        "mainTemplate": {
                            "parameters": [
                                "payload"
                            ],
                            "type": "Sequencer",
                            "items": [
                                {
                                    "type": "Audio",
                                    "source": "https://72578561-d9d8-47b4-811c-cafbcbc5ddb9-us-east-1.s3.amazonaws.com/Media/one-small-step-alexa-24.mp3"
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    },
                    "datasources": {}
                }
            ],
            "type": "_DEFAULT_RESPONSE"
        },
        "sessionAttributes": {},
        "userAgent": "ask-python/1.16.1 Python/3.7.12"
    }
}
```

> On my cloud Watch:
> [Cloud Watch](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pi6h6.png)

Answer (score 0):

Check without using Alexa

The [source url](https://72578561-d9d8-47b4-811c-cafbcbc5ddb9-us-east-1.s3.amazonaws.com/Media/one-small-step-alexa-24.mp3) you provided has an `AccessDenied` response.
This is what I'll do:

- Set temporary full public access to the s3 bucket to confirm that the audio works.

  - If the audio still doesn't work, upload the sample from Alexa that works on your S3 and try to play it with the S3 Object URL.
- Unset temporary full public access & provide S3 Signed URLs. [Example](https://github.com/dabblelab/alexa-hosted-s3-audio-example-skill)